# Visualizing collision rectangles in world space

Tags: opengl, transformation

I am calculating collision for my fps-camera by checking if the x/z-position of the camera is inside a plane. And the detection works fine. The plane is represented as two-component vectors min and max:

```
bool point_within_rectangle(glm::vec2 p, glm::vec2 min, glm::vec2 max)
{
    if ((p.x < max.x && p.x > min.x) && ((p.y < max.y && p.y > min.y)))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I am having problems visualizing the rectangles. This function draws a quad and creates an according vao if it wasn't created yet.

```
void RenderQuad(Geometry *geometry, vec3 min, vec3 max)
{
    if (geometry->vao == 0)
    {
        float quadVertices[] = {
            // positions        // texture Coords
            min.x, max.y, min.z, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            min.x, min.y, max.z, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            max.x, max.y, min.z, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            max.x, min.y, max.z, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        };
        // setup plane VAO
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &geometry->vao);
        glGenBuffers(1, &geometry->vbo);
        glBindVertexArray(geometry->vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry->vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices), &quadVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    }
    glBindVertexArray(geometry->vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

My idea was to render a quad like this:

```
vec2 min = vec2{-8.0f, -8.0f};
vec2 max = vec2{8.0f, 8.0f}

mat4 model = mat4(1.0f);
flat_shader.set_mat4("model", model);
RenderQuad(&navmesh_geometry, vec3{min.x, 0.0f, min.y}, vec3{max.x, 0.0f, max.y});
```

[image]

While this does work, it breaks when I try to render another quad which is not centered around world origin. In that case I still see only the above rectangle.

```
vec2 min2 = vec2{-13.0f, 1.0f};
vec2 max2 = vec2{-11.0f, 2.0f};
```

I am drawing both rectangles in a loop.

```
    for (std::vector<NavMesh>::iterator it_mesh = nav_meshes.begin(); it_mesh != nav_meshes.end(); ++it_mesh)
    {
        model = mat4(1.0f);
        flat_shader.set_mat4("model", model);
        RenderQuad(&navmesh_geometry,
                         vec3{it_mesh->min.x, 0.0f, it_mesh->min.y},
                         vec3{it_mesh->max.x, 0.0f, it_mesh->max.y});
    }
```

I can see the second rectangle if I don't draw the first one. I suppose that the problem lies in the assumption that the min max values in the vao are in world space, while they are in object space. That way I guess that the second rectangle is not visible because it is drawn around world origin occluded by the first rectangle.

My first approach was to center the `model` around it's calculated center by translating it.

```cpp
// Prepare..
mat4 model = mat4(1.0f);
model = translate(model, vec3{
    (it_mesh->min.x + it_mesh->max.x) / 2.0f,
    0.0f,
    (it_mesh->min.y + it_mesh->max.y) / 2.0f});
// Draw...
```

This seems to screw up the scale of the rectangle.

[image]

I guess I am missing the right rendering approach for this problem. How would I render a rectangle with the according `min` and `max` values in world space?

In case it helps my vertex and fragment shaders are straight forward.

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
// uv layout not used.

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform vec3 color;

void main() {
    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
```

`projection` and `view` are also correctly passed to the shader. I did not include that part in my snippets above.